# can i get a photo directlly from calllog.calls provider

Tags: android, android-contacts, calllog

i want to get a contact photo (if he has one) from the callLog.

now i know i can get the number and then query the contacts provider for a contact id.

however i want to know if there is a better way one that directly get the photo uri from the callLog.calls table.
what makes me believe it might be possible is the fact that inside the documentation i ran across 2 interesting fields:

1)**CACHED_LOOKUP_URI** -The cached URI to look up the contact associated with the phone number, if it exists.

2)**CACHED_PHOTO_ID** - The cached photo id of the picture associated with the phone number, if it exists.

now if it can be done how, and if it cant be done than i would like to know what those fields are used for,
thx

Comment: @ Gabriel H have you find solution for this,because I am having same problem while loading image  ,but loading photo from other cursor take time for multiple number

Comment: @Sagar2869767 nope i left that specific project a while ago and unfortunatlly haven't really figured out a better way than getting the contact number and then the photo, i can only suggest to do this in an asynchronous way so to not jam the app with loading time (put a default pic and swap it)

Comment: thanks for suggestion,for the while I am loading in asynchronous way .Still looking for better solution

Answer (score 1):

You can get its ID. Then you have to retrieve the actual image from ContactsContract.

```
imageDataRow = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID));
Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
    }, ContactsContract.Data._ID + "=?", new String[]{
            Integer.toString(imageDataRow)
    }, null);
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            imageBytes = c.getBlob(0);
        }
        c.close();
    }
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, I have used Glide to set an image on view. 
 **SDK>=23**

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI));
```

**SDK<23**

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(num));
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
            image_uri = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));
            //Log.d(TAG, "image_uri "+image_uri);
        }
        if(cursor !=null)
            cursor.close();
```